# Trouble making a simple API call with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is it that when I try to retrieve data with this simple API call I get an error that says http://127.0.0.1:8080/%7B%7Buser.avatar%7D%7D <- ? But if I move my promise into my controller it works. I thought that you can make your promises in your service and it'll work fine?

**This is my controller.js file**

```
angular.module('userProfiles').controller('MainController', function($scope, mainService) {

  $scope.getUsers = function() {
    mainService.getUsers();
  }
  $scope.getUsers();

});
```

**This is my services.js file**

```
angular.module('userProfiles').service('mainService', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://reqres.in/api/users?page=1';

  this.getUsers = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: baseUrl
    }).then(function(response) {
      this.users = response.data.data;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: you didn't list an error, you listed a url to a file on your local PC.  Perhaps you cut and pasted the wrong information when writing the question?

Comment: It occurred in my console log. In my get users function I pass in my baseUrl

Comment: that being said, your service will most likely not function the way you expect, because you can't use `this` inside a `.then` callback in this way.

Comment: the error in your console.log definitely isn't `http://127.0.0.1:8080/%7B%7Buser.avatar%7D%7D` and nothing else; even if it were, this doesn't correspond to anything in your code.

Comment: Use `ng-src="{{user.avatar}}"` instead of `src="{{user.avatar}}"`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning the `response.data.data` to anything usable outside that callback. Try it like this instead, returning a promise that resolves with the `users` data...

```
this.getUsers = function() {
    return $http.get('http://reqres.in/api/users', {
        params: {page: 1}
    }).then(function(res) {
        return res.data.data;
    });
};
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.getUsers = function() {
    mainService.getUsers().then(function(users) {
        $scope.users = users;
    });
};
```